# "ja nai" after a verb

Tags: grammar

1) Is the plain "ja nai" after a verb grammatically correct?

```
   aru ja nai?

   wakatta ja nai?
```

2) Why use ja nai, why not a negative form of a verb :

```
   aru ja nai? --> nai?

   wakatta ja nai? --> wakaranakatta?
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Are you sure what you're hearing/seeing doesn't have an ん after the first verb?  `あるん　じゃない？`  `わかったん　じゃない？`

Comment: Maybe if someones talking about the verb itself, treating it like a noun.

Answer (score 2):

あるじゃない{HLLLL} （ない{HL}）means "Look / Wow, there's (something)!".

あるじゃない{HLLLLH}？ means "By the way / You know, there's (something), right?".

あるじゃない{HLLLHL} means "It's not ある! / Shut up! Don't say ある!".

あるじゃないぃ{HLLLHLH}？ means "What? You mean, it's not ある?".

（だから）あるんじゃない{HLLLLL}（ない{HL}）means "(that's why) there's (something), no?".

あるんじゃない{HLLLLLH}？ means "I guess there's one".

あるんじゃない{HLLLLHL} means "It's not that there's one (but ...)".

あるんじゃないぃ{HLLLLHLH}？ means "(I thought there was but) you mean, it's not the case?"

Comment: can you provide  more natural examples? what's **"......, it's not ある?"**

Comment: Then, how about "Pardon? Did you say "it's not 「ある」"?"?

Comment: ありえないほど細かいですね。素晴らしいです。

Comment: I forgot to mention that the questions expressed with ないぃ？ are often accompanied with の and become ないの？ instead. This is probably for the purpose of earning an extra mora to indicate intonation.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the meaning of the phrases. The translation is:

```
あるじゃない？ = there is, no?
わかったじゃない？ = you understood it, right?
```

That is, it is a positive statement with a question whether it is true or not. You can parse it in two parts: わかった = you understood, じゃない = is not, where the first part functions as a adjective where the adjective describes a state of "you" in this case, so it is as if you are asking "is not (adjective)?"

Also, the natural way of saying a phrase like that is to add an ん after the verb. You can say without the ん but that becomes a bit "stiff"/"hard". Most likely the source where you heard this actually said:
あるんじゃない？

Comment: how about my 1st question?

Comment: Yes, it is gramatically correct, but normally people would add the ん between the parts as it makes it easier to pronounce.

Comment: and in this case it's very similar to "ne", right?

Comment: @koodi あるんじゃない is not interchangeable to あるじゃない (which is "see? / voila, there is!"). ね is not either with those two. They are all different.